# How to copy text from nano to OfficeLibre ?

Tags: pi-3b+

I can mark the nano file text - Ctrl +^ and copy it using Meta+^.
The text should be in some buffer , but 
I cannot use OfficeLibre "GUI" to paste this selection into Writer.
Apparently this "nano" buffer is not same as (widows) notepad.
I like to use OfficeLibre to index the text. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try highlighting the text with the mouse, then right clicking and choosing copy. To paste you can try ctrl-shift-c or right-clicking where you want the text.

Comment: Mouse will highlight only  current page , I need the entire file.

Comment: try ctrl-A ctrl-c

Comment: open the text file using Writer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using LibreOffice, I will assume you have a mouse too.

1. Select the contents of the terminal in nano using the mouse to `click and drag` the selection.
2. Press `Ctrl+Shift+c` to copy
3. Back in LibreOffice, press `Ctrl+v` to paste.

If you wish to use the keyboard only, you can follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/548448/283408) which allows you to switch buffers for copying!